# Dashboard filters exactly belongs to?

Tags: tableau-api

I have lot many data sources, dashboards and worksheets in one workbook, There are couple of filters on one dashboards, I want to know from dashboard which filter belongs to which worksheet or where this filter exactly belongs to ?

As well please share how to create Global filters and when they are used?

Comment: It would be best to separate your questions into two different postings.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at a dashboard in Desktop, you can click on a worksheet which will select the worksheet and you'll see four icons pop up (usually in top right corner, sometimes top left corner). The last icon is a downward triangle. Click it and you'll see a long menu with options such as Go To Sheet, Duplicate, and Fit. One option is labeled Filters. Click Filters and it opens a submenu of all filterable fields on the worksheet. If a field is being used as a filter in the dashboard, it will show a checkmark next to the field name.

Note that this is an easy way to add and remove filters from a dashboard. But in your case, you are using it to figure out which worksheet is doing the filtering.

Be aware that dashboards can have filter actions so sometimes worksheets will cascade the filter values to other worksheets on the dashboard.

[image]